# In Angular, how can I find the height of a div dynamically and use it in the HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular-directive

There are several answers here on SO that show how to determine the height of a div dynamically and log it to console. But what I want to do is to get the height of the div and assign it to a style in the HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv" myHeight>      
   <ion-scroll direction="y" style="height:{{height}}px">
   ...
</div>
```

I need to determine the height of myDiv and set it to the style as shown above.

This is what I tried, but looks like I don't understand directives well enough yet:

```
.directive('myHeight', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element) {
            scope.height = element[0].offsetHeight;
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: I'm confused- why are you attempting to set the height with CSS if it is the height already?

Comment: I don't know what the height of myDiv will be, but the ion-scroll directive (from ionic framework) requires me to set the height of myDiv in the style, so I'm trying to determine the rendered height of myDiv.

Comment: @MikelBitson, because OP get height from `div` and try set this value to `ion-scroll`

Comment: When adding directives on the HTML, you have to use lowercase: `my-height` instead of `myHeight`.

Comment: the element's style precedes the css style.

Comment: Either way, this could be accomplished with flex and css instead of requiring JS and it's own directive.

Comment: [Normalization](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#normalization)

Comment: What is the CSS of myDiv look like? If you don't use `min-height:100%` on `myDiv` then you can just set the `height:100%`  on `ion-scroll` and it will inherit the height of `myDiv`

Comment: @ShadowCodex I tried that first. However, myDiv is in the bottom half of the screen, but if I set it to 100%, it's taking the whole window's height.

Comment: @prabhu are you setting `height:100%` on myDiv or ion-scroll?

Comment: @ShadowCodex on ion-scroll

Comment: @ShadowCodex It's possible that I may be wrong, double checking now.

Comment: @Prabhu check out this jsfiddle that is similar to your situation. http://jsfiddle.net/je0r1yss/1/ See if that helps.

Comment: @ShadowCodex thanks, yeah I guess that makes sense. Something else might be going on at my end.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/94360/discussion-between-shadow-codex-and-prabhu).

Comment: Gimme a second and I'll be in that chat. Unblocking it from our dns.

Comment: So, I actually got this to work by using my-height instead of myHeight, but the height is not correct. I'm not sure if the directive is running before the view renders, but I tried it with $timeout, and that gives me 0 height.